# При нажатии на кнопку не меняется класс. В чем проблема?

Tags: javascript, html, css, функции

```js
function toggleVisibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e == 'shadowID') {
    e.className = 'shadowOn';
  } else {
    e = 'shadowID';
  };
}

var show = true;

function changeButton(el) {
  if (show) {
    el.innerText = "Скрыть";
    show = false;
  } else {
    el.innerText = "Показать полностью";
    show = true;
  };
}
```

```css
.shadowID {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showText {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadowOn {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadowID">
  <p>Привет! Этот текст должен быть длинным!<br> Очень длинным,и поэтому я тут напишу просто<br> много глупых предложений, которые никому не интересны.<br> Возможно это будет никому не интересно. А вот мне интересно.<br> Самое интересное в интересе, поэтому
    надо<br> делать кнопку которая будет показывать скрытый текст.<br> Если честно, то я хочу сделать это разными способами.<br> И я думаю, что я смогу.</p>
</div>
<div class="showText" onclick="toggleVisibility('shadowID'); changeButton(this)">Показать полностью</div>
```

Comment: Начнём с того, что, очевидно, на вашей странице нет ни одного элемента с идентификатором shadowID

Comment: Даже когда меня с класса на id то все равно не меняется ничего.

Comment: Потому что проверка `e == 'shadowID'` бессмысленна, HTML-элемент никогда в жизни не будет равен строке

Comment: Извините. Всегда готов к критике и люблю её. Просто начал все это изучать недавно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему не подключите JQuery к примеру?

```
$('.showText').on('click', function() {
   $('.shadowID').toggleClass('class');
});
```

Обьясните конкретно где класс меняется.

Либо JS:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".showText");
var blockChange = document.querySelector(".shadowID");

button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    button.classList.toggle("active");
    blockChange.classList.toggle("show-block");
});
```

Либо если нужно писать в файле html(оберните ваш js в тег script и вставьте перед закрывающим тегом body):

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.querySelector(".showText");
  var blockChange = document.querySelector(".shadowID");

  button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    button.classList.toggle("active");
    blockChange.classList.toggle("show-block");
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Я понимаю что JQuery намного удобнее и проще. Но пытаюсь сделать на обычном js. (Не учил JQuery).

Comment: Функция toggleVisibility(id).

Comment: @Александр Анцупов если вы будете работать на фирму, и вам нужно будет писать js, то не всегда вам будет разрешено писать его прямо в html. Лучше подключить внешний файл script.js и работать в нем. Пробуйте так. Ответ поправил.

Comment: Спасибо.Понимаю. Я для удобства писал в общем файле, потому что меня попросили все сделать в одном html файле.

Comment: Можете так же внизу под всем содержимым и перед </body>, написать такое <script type="text/javascript"></script> и там писать js. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Хорошо! Спасибо. ))

Comment: @Александр Анцупов если ответ вам подходит, нажмите на Галочку возле ответа чтоб отметить его как правильный, чтоб пользователи могли ориентироваться в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Ответ подходит, который на JQuery (сдался я с js). Сейчас найду ссылку на этот фреймворк, чтобы подключить. И придется изучать. Благодарю. ))))

Comment: @Александр Анцупов JQuery намного проще и доступней. Сам сразу учил jq. Прошу)

Answer (score 0):

В разметке присутствует:

```
<div class="shadowID">
```

Однако внутри функции `toggleVisibility` ищется `document.getElementById(id)`

Так как задан класс, а ищется по id - ничего и не находится.

Нужно либо изменить в разметке на id: `<div id="shadowID">`

либо искать по классу, воспользовавшись [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) либо [`getElementsByClassName`](http://org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (**важно:** возвращает коллекцию, а не один элемент, как предыдущая функция)

---

Кроме ошибки с поиском в коде присутствует странный `if`

```
if (e == 'shadowID') {
    e.className = 'shadowOn';
} else {
    e = 'shadowID';
};
```

Где элемент сначала сравнивается со строкой, затем либо меняется его класс, либо в переменную записывается строка.

Если нужно присвоить класс только элементу с определенным `id` то именно это и нужно делать и проверять нужно `id`

```
if(e.id == "shadowID")
    e.className = "shadowOn";
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.